# what is the difference between these two amp-video-iframes?

Tags: video, amp-html

What is the difference between the two ways to implement amp-video-frames? Is one version better than the other?

version 1

```
  <script async custom-element="amp-video-iframe" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-video-iframe-0.1.js"></script>
```

version 2

```
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/video-iframe-integration-v0.js"></script>


<!-- Wait for API to initialize -->
<script>
(window.AmpVideoIframe = window.AmpVideoIframe || [])
    .push(onAmpIntegrationReady);

function onAmpIntegrationReady(ampIntegration) {
  // `ampIntegration` is an object containing the tools required to integrate.
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `amp-video-iframe-0.1.js` JavaScript file is what is included in the head of your AMP page, where as the `video-iframe-integration-v0.js`file is what you'll include on the page where your video player lives that you'll be iFraming. They are two parts of the same integration.

You can find more information about this here: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-video-iframe

Comment: What if the video player is on the AMP page?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Add a video to the AMP page.

Comment: From where specifically? You might not need to use this component. This is used for implementing with video players on a non-AMP page that do not have a native AMP integration.

Comment: From where? Do you mean where is the video stored? On my server.  If the page is non-AMP why would I use the amp-video-iframe? I would just install it via standard techniques

Comment: If you are just trying to play a video directly from its source, you can just use `amp-video` instead of `amp-video-iframe`.  `amp-video-iframe` is for if you have a third party video player that you would like to use on the page that does not have an existing AMP component.